# How to correctly split strings in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, split, jstl

How can I split strings separated by "/" inside a jsp page using JSTL?

I have a string in this format:
**

> "23/11/2010"

**. Sometimes, the string could be like this: **

> "1/1/2010"

**.
I need to do something in order to split the string in three different substrings:
**

> "23", "11", "2010".

**
This is because I need to put each one of them inside three different text fields, like these:

```
<input type="text" value="23">/
<input type="text" value="11">/
<input type="text" value="2010">
```

I could not find any working example yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the [`fn:split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/split.fn.html) function for this.

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<c:set var="dateParts" value="${fn:split(dateString, '/')}" />
...
<input type="text" name="day" value="${dateParts[0]}" />
<input type="text" name="month" value="${dateParts[1]}" />
<input type="text" name="year" value="${dateParts[2]}" />
```

Be sure that the date format is validated beforehand :) It would be easier if it was a `java.util.Date`, not a `java.lang.String`. You could then use [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) to format it to a reliable and fixed string format first. Otherwise you'd need to add checks on array length by [`fn:length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/length.fn.html) and to prevent potential XSS attack holes by [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html).

Also important to note is that the function takes a regular expression as argument and not just a plain character sequence. So in case you'd like to split on characters which represent special characters in regex, then you'd need to escape them with backslashes. See also [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) for general guidelines which also apply to `fn:split()`.

Comment: Can I use foreach on this?

Answer (score 11):

It's worth noting for anyone else who finds this question in their searching (as I did) that JSTL has the useful tag `<c:forTokens>`.
This will split the input string by a supplied delimiter and then iterate over the resultant collection of tokens.

As demonstrated here, the following code:

```
<c:forTokens items="A,B,C,D" delims="," var="mySplit">
   <c:out value="${mySplit}"/></br>
</c:forTokens>
```

Would result in:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Documentation: [JSTL core Tag forTokens](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forTokens.html)

Answer (score 5):

Use the JSTL fn library.  They have a [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/split.fn.html) in there.