# jstl split function

Tags: function, split, jstl

I wanted to split a given string using jstl 1.2
eg:

```
Bean thesis.url contains "http:website1.com : http:website2.com"
which needs to be splited into
http:website1.com
http:website2.com

<c:set var="url">
  <c:out value="${thesis.url}" />
</c:set>  

<c:set var="offUrls" value="${fn:split(url,' : ')}" />
<c:forEach items="${offUrls}" var="link">
    <a href=" <c:out value='${link}' />" target="_blank">
        <c:out value="${link}" />
    </a>
</c:forEach>
```

But the output is not want I wanted which is
 http
 website1.com
 http
 website2.com

I tried another way, and its dint work either.
 
 `<c:set var="_split" value= " : "/>

   <c:set var="offUrls" value="${fn:split(url,_split)}" />`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correctly split strings in JSTL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304084/how-to-correctly-split-strings-in-jstl)

Comment: @JBNizet: sorry for delay as I was trying to edit my post.and since I was just trying to familarising with adding a post in sov which i find it difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fn:split` will split your string on any of the delimiter characters, so in your case both space and `:`. The solution is to do a `fn:replace` first:

```
<c:set var="urls" value="http://website1.com : http://website2.com"/>
<c:set var="urls" value="${fn:replace(thesis.url, ' : ', '|')}"/>
```

Make sure to replace the separator with a character that is not present in your string, or else you will run into the same problem. Now you can use `fn:split(urls, '|')`, but it would be easier to use [`<c:forTokens/>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html#wp74001):

```
<c:forTokens items="${urls}" delims="|" var="url">
  <a href="${url}">${url}</a>
</c:forTokens>
```

A better solution would be to simply do the work at the back end of your application and pass a list of strings to the front end.

Comment: Brilliant! I assumed the fn:split() will work as the same way as String split(). Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: Can you pls clarify the difference between      <a href=" <c:out value='${url}' />" >    <c:out value="${url}" />      </a>  and       <a href="${url}">${url}</a>

Comment: `<c:out/>` will escape characters like `&`, `<` and `>`.