# split a word if the word has capitalised words in between using JSTL

Tags: jstl

I want to split a word using JSTL

PaperTag: Paper, Tag

and i want to store it as:

```
word[0]: Paper;  
word[1]: Tag;
```

I couldn't find any specific way to do this on google.

Comment: I think you can get help here  
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604344/jstl-split-function][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604344/jstl-split-function  

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can split string with `JSTL`

```
<c:set var="word" value="${fn:split('Paper, Tag', ',')}" />
```

For more: [SPLIT WITH JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_split.htm)