# How to split number in a jstl variable

Tags: jstl, substring

I have this value

```
<c:set var="string1" value="SS4444"/>
```

What I am try to achieve is to get the numbers only (4444) from the above variable. I can use substring, but the index value might change, ie it can be 'SS4444', 'S4444', 'SSS444', so cant rely on static index.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304084/how-to-correctly-split-strings-in-jstl

Look at this answer.

Comment: Hey thanks, but it wont help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it with regex.. (substringAfter is not proper for this..):

```
<c:forEach var="string1" items="${fn:split(yourstring, '^\w*')}">
                    <c:set var="string2" value="${string1}"/> 
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with replace function as:

```
    <c:set var="strng" value="SS4444"/>

    <c:set var="strng1" value="${fn:replace(strng,'S','')}"/>
```