# when using jstl {fn:split} how write '@'?

Tags: java, jquery, jstl

i have to use "jstl" in my project
and split email address separate with '@'

so i coded

```
$('#Email1').val('${fn:split(user.user_email,'@')[0]}');
```

but there is error come up.

```
error message is: "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"
```

what's wrong? and what should i modify here?

now i'm using "jquery", "jsp", "spring"
and this is jsp page script sector

if there is another way to split in jstl
could you let me know?

```
$('#email2').val('${fn:split(user.user_email,'@')[1]}');
```

thank you for your answer

Comment: *but there is error come up* What does the error say?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304084/how-to-correctly-split-strings-in-jstl

Comment: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: I don't know JSTL, but the examples I'm seeing elsewhere always seem to include something like `<c:set var="usereMail" value="${fn:split(user.user_email,'@')[0]}" />` And then you would use `$('#email2').val('${userEmail[0]}');`

Comment: wow it's good for me