# How to split a string from another string in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jstl-functions

I am new to JSTL and figuring out a way to split a string using another string. For example supppose my string is

```
s= "Hello! Good Morning",
```

and the

```
t = "Good ",
```

then I should have str[0] = 'Hello! ' and str[1] = 'Morning'. 
However if I put this into

```
${fn:split(s, t)}
```

it is removing all 'G','o','d' and ' '.

Thanks

Comment: [look here for some understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304084/how-to-correctly-split-strings-in-jstl) and probably use google as well

Answer (score 0):

`fn:split` will split your string on any of the delimiter characters, so simply use the replace function `fn:replace` to pick up a more convenient delimiter.

```
<c:set var = "newString" value = "${fn:replace(s, t, '-')}"/>
```

Then you can use split without problems:

```
${fn:split(newString, '-')}
```